# Use of unresolved identifier 'GMSAutocompleteSessionToken'

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

In the Places SDK for iOS (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete), when we implement Get place predictions programmatically (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically) It requires to create a new session token.

In this Line
`let token = GMSAutocompleteSessionToken.init()`

Xcode says `Use of unresolved identifier 'GMSAutocompleteSessionToken'`
I already

```
import GooglePlaces
```

How to correctly use this **GMSAutocompleteSessionToken** ?

Answer (score 0):

Import GoogleMapsBase as well

```
import GoogleMapsBase
```

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete#session_tokens

Comment: This is not solved my issue :(. Thank you for the support

Answer (score 0):

First time my pods were not updated. So I tried to forcefully with

```
'GooglePlaces', '~> 3.0.0'
```

I had to add

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'app_name' do
```

This solved my issue.